# std::complex<> in C++ math special functions: technical specification or proposal

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std, cmath

In C++17, [mathematical special functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_functions) (such as Bessel functions, for example) were added to the standard and are already relatively well supported by modern compilers.

However, those functions are defined for real-valued arguments, while some applications in computational physics heavily use their complex equivalents.

I wonder if

- there is/were any technical specifications/proposals for enhancing [`std::complex<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) with special functions (I was not able to find anything related)
- if such a proposal is in the active state and has a chance for, I guess, C++23
- there are considerations against including special math functions for `std::complex<>` besides their [relatively] narrow use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know of no such proposal currently under review.

I would expect such a proposal to come through SG6 (the numerics study group).